# How do I know which cursor style the browser sets for a particular element

Tags: javascript, css

How do I know which cursor style the browser sets for a particular element when using the "cursor: auto" CSS value?

I would like to know what "auto" evaluates to for a certain element when hovering that element.

element.style.cursor just returns "auto", while I would like to know the evaluated value ("text", "pointer"...) when hovering the element.

In a mouseover listener:

```
let cursorStyle = window.getComputedStyle(e.target, null).cursor;
console.log(cursorStyle); // outputs "auto", not "text" when hovering a div / p with text
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have no chance at all. According to spec, the default CSS value for cursor is `auto` (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor) that means the browser takes it on his own.

Your script is working well and gives you the right answer (the value of `cursor` style property). In auto mode, the browser logically do not update the property (well, `auto` is staying `auto`, not changing every time).

Maybe there's some hacks to guess the cursor based on the hovered object but it will be quite painful to implement.